# Page Reload Not Working

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using Fancybox 2 to create a lightbox with the delete form inside the lightbox.

I'm able to delete a record successfully via PHP however, to show that record is no longer in the table, I need to reload the page. I've tried to use `header()` then `window.location.href=window.location.href;` to redirect the user back to the current page, and in this example I'm JavaScript to try and reload the page, without any luck. Any ideas what I might be missing?

```
if(isset($_POST['confirm']))
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM ". $dbname ." WHERE ". $id ." =  ". $record;
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            location.reload();
        </script>";
}
```

Here is the markup.

```
<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this row?</h3>
<form action="" method="POST">
        <input onclick="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="confirm" value="Yes">
        //Don't worry about this button
        <input onclick="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();" class="btn btn-danger" value="No">
</form>
```

Comment: The record has been really deleted? Because you are using `onclick="...fancybox.close();"`... Your PHP code has been called?

Comment: It is. The lightbox closes, and the record still remains on the page, once I refresh the page, the record has disappeared from the page and the DB.

Comment: I would suggest that you put the `location.reload()` after the `...fancybox.close();`. Such like this: `onclick="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();parent.location.reload();"`

Comment: Considering that the code is executed from a frame, we need a "parent" prefix.